# Why does my video segmentation model predict only one value across the entire output array?

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I'm working on a video segmentation model, inspired by UNet and VNet. I'm trying to benchmark the model by overfitting it on a single video (done with a 5e-4 learning rate on 5 epochs of 8 steps, with each step being the same video). However, when it predicts values after being trained, the numbers are all the same. For example, when displaying one of the frames of the generated video, its all gray. How can I fix this?